# Recommended way to IntelliJ IDEA when part of my programming is in Wolfram Language?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

I installed IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.1 and found a Wolfram language plug-in in the plug-in market. But it is not free and only compatible with an older version of IntelliJ IDEA. Besides keeping two versions of IntelliJ IDEA, one compatible with that plug-in, and the other the newest released version, is there a good way to use IntelliJ IDEA when only an insignificant portion of my programming is in Wolfram Language?

Comment: You can contact the author of the IntelliJ plugin directly: https://wlplugin.halirutan.de/contact/